# Memory leaks with AddressBook framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, addressbook, abaddressbook

I'm having some memory leaks with both ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID and ABPersonSetImageData. I've been looking for solutions before posting here but I still don't understand. If I play quite a long time with the iPhone 3GS or with only a few contacts with iPhone 3G, actually the application crashes.  Here is my code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. I've seen sample codes with these methods and I don't see what I'm missing. Thank you in advance. (sorry for mistakes...)

```
Contact *myContact = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cancelCreateContact = NO;


ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
int len = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(ab);
ABRecordID contactID;
ABRecordRef person;
BOOL alreadyExists = NO;
CFStringRef first, last;

for(int i = 1; i < (len + 1); i++)
{
    person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ab, (ABRecordID)i);

    if(!person){
        len++;
        continue;
    }

    first = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    last = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    if ([[(NSString*)first lowercaseString] isEqualToString:[myContact.firstname lowercaseString]] && [[(NSString*)last lowercaseString] isEqualToString:[myContact.lastname lowercaseString]]) {
        alreadyExists = YES;
        contactID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
        break;
    }
}

if (alreadyExists) {
    //NSLog(@"already exists");
    ABRecordRef aContactFound = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ab, contactID);

    ABRecordRef aRecord = ABPersonCreate();

    CFErrorRef anError = NULL;

    CFStringRef firstname = ABRecordCopyValue(aContactFound, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, firstname, &anError);
    CFRelease(firstname);

    CFStringRef lastname = ABRecordCopyValue(aContactFound, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonLastNameProperty, lastname, &anError);
    CFRelease(lastname);

    CFStringRef job = ABRecordCopyValue(aContactFound, kABPersonJobTitleProperty);
    ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonJobTitleProperty, job, &anError);
    CFRelease(job);

    ABMultiValueRef instantMessage = ABRecordCopyValue(aContactFound, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty);
    ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty, instantMessage, &anError);
    CFRelease(instantMessage);

    ABMultiValueRef phone = ABRecordCopyValue(aContactFound, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phone, &anError);
    CFRelease(phone);

    ABMultiValueRef email = ABRecordCopyValue(aContactFound, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonEmailProperty, email, &anError);
    CFRelease(email);

    CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(aContactFound);
    ABPersonSetImageData(aRecord, imageData, &anError);
    ABAddressBookSave(ab, &anError);
    CFRelease(imageData);

    ABUnknownPersonViewController *ABView = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];
    ABView.unknownPersonViewDelegate = self;
    ABView.displayedPerson = aRecord;
    ABView.allowsAddingToAddressBook = NO;
    ABView.allowsActions = YES;
    ABView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ABView animated:YES];

    [ABView release];

    CFRelease(aRecord);

}else{
    //NSLog(@"doesn't exist");
    //sinon ouvre une fiche pré-remplie

    ABRecordRef aRecord = ABPersonCreate();

    CFErrorRef anError = nil;

    if(![myContact.firstname isEqualToString:@""]) ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, myContact.firstname, &anError);

    if(![myContact.lastname isEqualToString:@""]) ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonLastNameProperty, myContact.lastname, &anError);

    if(![myContact.email isEqualToString:@""]) {
        ABMultiValueRef ABemail = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(ABemail, myContact.email, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonEmailProperty, ABemail, &anError);
        CFRelease(ABemail);
    }

    if(![myContact.phone_business isEqualToString:@""] || ![myContact.phone_mobile isEqualToString:@""]){ 
        ABMultiValueRef ABphones = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        if(![myContact.phone_business isEqualToString:@""]) ([myContact.phone_business stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]].length == 4 || [myContact.phone_business stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]].length == 5) ? ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(ABphones, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"014443%@", myContact.phone_business], kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL) : ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(ABphones, myContact.phone_business, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
        if(![myContact.phone_mobile isEqualToString:@""] && ([myContact.phone_mobile stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]].length == 10)) ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(ABphones, myContact.phone_mobile, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonPhoneProperty, ABphones, &anError);
        CFRelease(ABphones);
    }

    if(![myContact.job isEqualToString:@""]) ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonJobTitleProperty, myContact.job, &anError);

    if(![myContact.msn isEqualToString:@""] || ![myContact.twitter isEqualToString:@""] || ![myContact.facebook isEqualToString:@""]){  
        ABMultiValueRef ABmessaging = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
        NSMutableDictionary *dMessaging;

        if(![myContact.msn isEqualToString:@""]){
            dMessaging = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [dMessaging setObject:myContact.msn forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey];
            [dMessaging setObject:@"MSN" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey];
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(ABmessaging, dMessaging, kABPersonInstantMessageServiceMSN, NULL);
            [dMessaging release];
        }

        if(![myContact.twitter isEqualToString:@""]){
            dMessaging = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [dMessaging setObject:myContact.twitter forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey];
            [dMessaging setObject:@"Twitter" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey];
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(ABmessaging, dMessaging, kABOtherLabel, NULL);
            [dMessaging release];
        }

        if(![myContact.facebook isEqualToString:@""]){
            dMessaging = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [dMessaging setObject:myContact.facebook forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey];
            [dMessaging setObject:@"Facebook" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey];
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(ABmessaging, dMessaging, kABOtherLabel, NULL);
            [dMessaging release];

        }


        ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty, ABmessaging, &anError);
        CFRelease(ABmessaging);
    }

    //pas dans l'XMLToObjectParser parce que ça prenait une plombe...
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myContact.picture_path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    if(!data){
        NSString *picture_path = (![myContact.gender isEqualToString:@""]) ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"default_%@_head.png", [myContact.gender lowercaseString]] : @"default_m_head.png";

        [myContact setPicture_path:picture_path];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"pb lors de l'enregistrement de picture path");
        }

        //NSData *localData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myContact.picture_path];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:picture_path];
        NSData *localData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);   

        CFDataRef cfLocalData = CFDataCreate(NULL, [localData bytes], [localData length]);
        ABPersonSetImageData(aRecord, cfLocalData, &anError);
        ABAddressBookSave(ab, &anError);
        CFRelease(cfLocalData);

    }else {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        NSString *extension = [(NSArray*)[myContact.picture_path componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:1];

        NSData *localData = ([extension isEqualToString:@"png"]) ? UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) : UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);   

        CFDataRef cfLocalData = CFDataCreate(NULL, [localData bytes], [localData length]);
        ABPersonSetImageData(aRecord, cfLocalData, &anError);
        ABAddressBookSave(ab, &anError);
        CFRelease(cfLocalData);
    }

    if (anError != nil) { NSLog(@"error :: %@", anError); } 



    ABUnknownPersonViewController *ABView = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];
    ABView.unknownPersonViewDelegate = self;
    ABView.displayedPerson = aRecord;
    ABView.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;
    ABView.allowsActions = YES;
    ABView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ABView animated:YES];


    [ABView release];

    CFRelease(aRecord);

}
CFRelease(ab);
```

Comment: ", actually the application crashes..." We need the crash info. Is it a BAD ACCESS ?

Comment: It is an exc_bad_access error. I'm going to check that values are not NULL before CFRelease

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Firstly:** read up on your Core Foundation memory management. You don't yet know the rules by heart.

**Secondly:** when a CF-friendly function has "Copy" in the name, you must check its result for `NULL`, and release that result when done if it's not `NULL`. So this:

```
first = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

Will become a memory leak if it's never followed by `CFRelease(first);`.

**Thirdly:** if a Core Foundation value is `NULL`, passing it to `CFRelease` will crash:

```
CFStringRef firstname = ABRecordCopyValue(aContactFound, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, firstname, &anError);
CFRelease(firstname);
```

If `firstname` is `NULL` (which it could be--imagine a contact named simply "Smith") then a crash *will* happen.

Comment: It was an exc_bad_access error. I read the Core Foundtation Memory Management and added CFRelease for first and last but it crashed so I removed but you're totally right some Contacts didn't get lastname or firstname, so it was logical... Instruments pointed the line with ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID but perhaps it's not really reliable. I'm going to change it immediately, thank you

Comment: **Always** follow your Get/Copy/Create calls with an `if (...)` test to determine whether there's a valid result. Any of these APIs can return `NULL`.

Comment: I haven't memory leaks with ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID anymore, thank you. I think the problem I still have with ABPersonSetImageData is due to image format I don't specify (thumbnail, etc)

Comment: That is probably not a true leak based on the code you've presented here. The leak is likely elsewhere (some other component is not being released, and it ultimately owns the image.)

Comment: i am having leak with ABPersonSetImageData also, i'm 100% sure its that line, when commented out i have no leaks. Weird.

Comment: Perhaps you should seek out help with your problem on Stack Overflow by asking a question, rather than commenting on someone else's. ;)